# How Does Test Planning Differ for Manual and Automation Projects?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, test-planning

I am now into automation projects. So can anyone help how the test plan will differ from manual and automation projects.?

Comment: See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12307/8992

Comment: See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1703/8992

Comment: What is the current plan/Strategy in the given project? Are you just new to automation or automation is new in the project itself?

Comment: What is the current tech stack & team structure of the project?

Comment: Without all background info , it is difficult to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Test Planning for Manual Projects:

- How many people do we need?
- How many people do we have?
- What physical machines will be used?
- How will results be recorded and collated?
- What is the volume of work that needs to be done?
- What is the skill set of the people doing the testing?

#### Test Planning for Automation Projects

- What cloud services will be used?
- What do we need for a devops pipeline?
- What programming language is being used?
- How many automation engineer do we need?
- How many automation engineers do we have?
- What technology are we using for automation?
- How do we structure our smoke-happy-sad tests?
- How to write automation code that is maintainable?
- What should we still use exploratory manual testing for?
- What unique screens do we need to ensure are visited?
- What form of output do we need to show what was tested?
- How will UI automation relate to Unit and Integrated Testing?
- Are we running tests in the cloud, using CI/CD, or just locally?
- How will we handle intermittent failures (inherent in web testing)?
- What development environment will automation engineers need?
- In addition to the automation what should still be manually tested?
- Are we using other services such as Jira that we want to integrate?
- What services do we use for multi-device and multi-browser testing?
- How to test usability when most automation is presence of elements?

You will also need to distinguish UI testing from Unit and Integrated testing.  Manual testers are used to testing 'everything through the UI' leading to massive and slow test suites.  When you automate manual testing you need to ensure that *most* of your tests actually become unit tests that test the algorithm on the back end and not just the final display on a screen.  In order to do this observe the test pyramid and use it as a gude for structuring your tests

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDurrant

Comment: You are welcome.  Please consider up-voting and accepting my answer if you find it the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the few automation test plan that are performed by software testing company in project:-

1. Pick automation tools/language based on the following rules:

Does the company already have licenses for a certain tool, try and see if you can use it.

Look for open source(but reliable) tools

Do the team members know the tool already or do we need to bring in someone new? Or train the existing ones?

2.What automation framework need to be created. Always look for a middle ground and do the best you can without over utilization of resources.

3.Choose a team well versed with AUT, test management, defect management and other SDLC activities

4.The target environment that your AUT is going to run and the automation tool that you want to use should be compatible.

5.Most important part is selection of testcases/scenarios for automation. Choose the test cases/scenarios that are to be regressed over and over across multiple cycles.

6.Include time for code-walkthroughs and inspection of the automation scripts

7.Plan on creating a “How-to” document that will help the current users and future team members to be able to understand the script even when you are not around.
Include comments in your script too.
Do not hard code any test data into the scripts. This just leads to too much script maintenance and might induce errors during modification.